# Is it correct to use "had been in pawn"?

Tags: idioms

I found a question and an answer from an exercise. It is as follows:

> Q. The earrings had been in ………… before he noticed.
>
> A.  pawn

I'd like to know whether *"were in pawn"* should be used without using *"had been in pawn"*.

Comment: Could you clarify what "noticed" means? Does it mean "he realized it" or "he received some notice (it was in pawn)" or ??? Sorry I can't follow the logic.

Comment: @user3169. I'd like to know whether "the earrings were in pawn" should be used without using "the earrings had been in pawn".

Answer (score 3):

The idiom is correct.

The rest of the sentence is dubious.

One of these work better:

- *The earrings had been in pawn **for some time** before he noticed.*
- *The earrings were in pawn before he noticed.*
- *The earrings had (already) been pawned before he noticed.*
- *The earrings had been put in pawn before he noticed.*

Comment: Exactly. I wonder why I am downvoted!

Comment: They can at least post an answer in such cases. Helps to understand if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct.

*Had been in pawn* here refers to the fact that the earrings were left as security deposit in exchange for money until he noticed them.

Comment: I think It is incorrect to use 'had been in pawn'  in past perfect tense.

Comment: And why do you think so?

Comment: I think it should be simple past, 'were in pawn'.

Comment: Won't that depend on the context? As a standalone sentence, *had been in pawn* is grammatically correct.

Comment: The sentence is not a standalone sentence.

Comment: You question doesn't provide that information. Kindly edit your question to provide all necessary details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70263/discussion-between-thein-lwin-and-cincout).